# Firebase : Retrieving the whole data by using the value of a key without knowing the key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I had some querying question. So lets say that my database in Firebase is structured as so:

```
beers 
 |--*UniqueID*
        |-------beerName : "Ballast" 
        |-------beerStyle: "ipa"
```

and lets say that I have a list that contains both beer name and the beerStyle: `[Ballast, IPA, ... ]`. Is there a way to retrieve the whole beer object by using just the value of the key where you do not know the current key?

Here's what I've seen via the API and what I have so far:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("beers");
ref.orderByChild("???").equalTo(container[i]).on("child_added",    
  function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data){ console.log(data.val())
  });
```

Is there a way to retrieve the snapshot without specifying a key, which would go inside `orderByChild()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try orderByChild("beerName") , as it will get the node with beerName which is euqal to your required one, and then use DataSnapshot to retrieve values.

Comment: wont work because my entires in the container have values from both keys(beerName and beerStyle)